# Associate a wine program to right click

Tags: wine, menu, adobe-reader

I've just installed Adobe Reader XI on ubuntu 14.04, but I can't have this program on right click. I used to some times ago, but I don't remember how to do that.

I tried some `.desktop` file in `.local/Applications` directory but I can't have AR in other application in contextual menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you install Adobe Reader with Wine (and maybe other programs) to have this program available in the right-click menu, you have to use a `.desktop` file in the `.local/applications` directory such as:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Adobe Reader XI
Exec=env WINEPREFIX="/home/nico/.wine" wine C:\\\\windows\\\\command\\\\start.exe /Unix /home/nico/.wine/dosdevices/c:/users/nico/Start\\    
Menu/Programs/Adobe\\ Reader\\ XI.lnk %f
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
```

By default, the `%f` at the end of the exec line isn't here and you'll have to add it or the program doesn't appear in the nautilus menu.

[Source](https://ubuntugenius.wordpress.com/2012/06/18/ubuntu-fix-add-program-to-list-of-applications-in-open-with-when-right-clicking-files-in-nautilus/)

Comment: Although your answer is 100% correct, it might also become 100% useless if that link is moved, changed, merged into another one or the main site just disappears... **:-(** Therefore, please [edit] your answer, and copy the relevant steps from the link into your answer, thereby guaranteeing your answer for 100% of the lifetime of this site! **;-)** You can always leave the link in at the bottom of your answer as a source for your material...

Comment: The one who has downvoted could give an explanaition, then I could avoid to make the same mystake next time ;-)

Comment: Well, good lock with that one! (FWIW: I didn't)  Please also install a spell-checker... I'll edit your answer a bit more...

Comment: What is good lock?

Comment: Faute de frappe de "bonne chance"...  :P

Comment: Merci Fabby pour toute la remise en forme et les corrections. Mais comme tu m'avais blagué avec le spell-shaker ;-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26530/discussion-between-fabby-and-tarass).